# How to take multiple integers as single input separated by space in java, then break them into integers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, numbers, cube

**Need to take input 1 2 3 or of any length separated by space**
then break it into separate integers. 
I have tried `array`, `Strings` and `CharAt()` , `string.split()` method but they are not working.

Input can be 1 2 3 4 or 1 2 or of any length, we need to separate 1,2,3 as integers.

I have tried so far:

```
class Cube{ 
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
    int i,j=0,sum=0; int arr[]=new int[10]; 
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
    String s=scan.nextLine(); 
    int len =s.length(); 
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++){ 
        String[] str=s.split(" "); 
        int i=str[j]; sum+=Math.pow(3,i); j++; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: That should work actually. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: class Cube{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i,j=0,sum=0;
        int arr[]=new int[10];
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        int len =s.length();
        for(i=0;i<=len;i++){
        String[] str=s.split(" ");
            int i=str[j];
            sum+=Math.pow(3,i);
            j++;
        }
    }   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing the string to int. You need to use `Integer.parseInt()`. Also, use of `BufferedReader` is preferred.

```
class Cube{ 
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
    int i,j=0,sum=0; int arr[]=new int[10]; 
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
    String s=scan.nextLine(); 

    String[] str=s.split(" ");
    for(i=0;i<=str.length;i++){ 
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
        sum+=Math.pow(3,temp); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You should remove
 int len = s.length(); since it is not used

Comment: worked class Cube{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i,sum=0;
        int temp=0;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        String[] str=s.split(" ");
        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            temp=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            sum+=temp*temp*temp;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }   
}

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke `String.split` you will get a `String[]`. In Java 8+, you could stream it (and map to `int`) and then convert to an array like

```
String str = "1 2 3";
int[] arr = Stream.of(str.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Also,

```
sum+=Math.pow(3,i);
```

is 3<sup>i</sup>, I believe you wanted

```
sum+=(i * i * i);
```

**or**

```
sum+=Math.pow(i, 3);
```

Putting that together, to sum the cubes of `int`(s) in your `String` you could do,

```
int sum = Stream.of(str.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .map(x -> x * x * x).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Cube{ 
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
    int i,sum=0; int arr[]=new int[10]; 
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
    String s=scan.nextLine(); 

    String[] str = s.split(" "); 
    int len = str.length; 
    System.out.print(len);
    for(i=0; i < len; i++){ 
        int i1= Integer.parseInt(str[i]); 
        sum += Math.pow(3,i1);  
    } 
    System.out.println(sum);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration of converting the required input to 3 int the power of entered numbers:

```
    class Cube{
      public static void main(String args[]){

          int sum = 0;
          //input
          System.out.println("Eneter whole numbers seperated by space: ");
          Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
          String s=scan.nextLine();

          //remove spaces and get an array of strings
          String[] str = s.split(" ");
          int len = str.length;
          int ints[]=new int[len]; //this array can be omitted

          for(int i=0; i < len; i++){

              //convert array of string to ints
              //this is needed just for demonstration
              ints[i] = Integer.valueOf(str[i]);

              sum += Math.pow(3,Integer.valueOf(str[i] ));

          }

          //printout
          System.out.println("Input converted to int: "+ Arrays.toString(ints));
          System.out.println("Sum of 3 in the power of values entered : "+ sum);
         }
    }
```

This is of course a very fragile and basic code, without any input verification nor handling of exceptions.

This is slightly better :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Cube{
      public static void main(String args[]){

          int sum = 0;   final String SPACE = " ";

          //input
          System.out.println("Eneter whole numbers seperated by space: ");
          Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
          String s=scan.nextLine();

          //remove spaces and get an array of strings
          String[] str = s.split(SPACE);

          for(String intAsString : str){

              try {
                  sum += Math.pow(3,Integer.valueOf(intAsString));
              } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println(intAsString+ " can not be converted to integer");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
          }

          //printout
          System.out.println("Sum of 3 in the power of values entered : "+ sum);
         }
    }
```